# Electron auto updates through amazon s3 not working

Tags: amazon-s3, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I am trying to setup electron auto-updater with amazon s3 bucket.  I don't get any errors but when I publish a new version, the auto updater doesn't show any updates on the app screen. But the latest version that has been published shows up in amazon s3 bucket. Below shows how its added:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
const aws4 = require('aws4');
const pkg = require('./package.json');
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, protocol, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const log = require('electron-log');
const {autoUpdater} = require("electron-updater");

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
  alert('checking')
  console.log('checking for updates')
  const opts = {
    service: 's3',
      region: pkg.build.publish.region,
      method: 'GET',
      host: `s3-${pkg.build.publish.region}.amazonaws.com`,
      path: path.join('/', pkg.build.publish.bucket, latest_yml_path)
  };
  
  aws4.sign(opts, {
    accessKeyId: 'access key',
    secretAccessKey: 'secret access key'
  });
  // signer.sign(opts); --remove this line --
  autoUpdater.requestHeaders = opts.headers
  document.getElementById('messages').innerText = "checking for updates"
  sendStatusToWindow('Checking for update...');
})

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  alert('update available')
  sendStatusToWindow('Update available.');
})
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow('Update not available.');
})
autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  sendStatusToWindow('Error in auto-updater. ' + err);
})
autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
  let log_message = "Download speed: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
  log_message = log_message + ' - Downloaded ' + progressObj.percent + '%';
  log_message = log_message + ' (' + progressObj.transferred + "/" + progressObj.total + ')';
  sendStatusToWindow(log_message);
})
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  sendStatusToWindow('Update downloaded');
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the Menu
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
  console.log('ready')
  
  createDefaultWindow();
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});
```

No error shows up, but no messages show up too. Where is it possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some tips to you.

1. check opts.headers' that header is correct. (If request url from aws4 doesn't correct, it is not work.)
2. setFeedURL after autoUpdater header setting.
3. when download update package, you change autoUpdater header(and setFeedUrl) for updater package path. Because when checking for updates, you set header about yaml file path to autoUpdater.